# is there any iNFRAGISTICS control eqivalent to MonthCalendar control of .NET

Tags: infragistics, calendar-control

I am looking for a control in infragistics which is similar to month calendar control of .Net.
Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what platform that you are looking for, but here are links to the calendar/schedule controls available:

- [WebSchedule](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webschedule.aspx#Overview)
- [WebDatePicker & WebMonthCalendar](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/taz_abdeali/archive/2009/04/27/asp-net-april-2009-ctp-released.aspx) (Based on ASP.NET AJAX Framework - April 2009 CTP)
- [WinSchedule](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winschedule.aspx#Overview)
- [xamMonthCalendar](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamMonthCalendar.aspx#Overview)